# Updating JSON files in an ionic app

Tags: json, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic app and there are few json files in the www/dataFiles folder. I need to package these files with the app. However, once installed on a device these json files need to be updated periodically with new data from a server. I was searching for days trying to figure out how to do it and I found out that files in the www folder cannot be rewritten. I have no clue how to move forward. Do I have to save files in a different location? I would really appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify files on an already installed app.

Why not pull this data from a web service? Instead of storing the data on separate .json files, get that same json data from the server as a request and you will always have fresh data from the server.

What are you using as a server/database? With this information I can put you in the right path.

Comment: Thank for the reply Alejandro. Thing is the app will be running on devices where WiFi and mobile data coverage will not be available most of the time. But whenever it is connected to WiFi I want it to check for updates and download them.

Comment: Oh I get it, so maybe you can use a database like SQLite or IndexedDB and make a Sync function that gets the new data when they have internet connection.

Here is an article that can help you out:
http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check out the article.